# Room database created in Kotlin, activity written in Java, can I do that?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I have an activity and other stuff written in Java but don't want to convert to Kotlin yet. Now that I need to create a Room Database and I want to use Kotlin for that. If I do that, can my java programs access the Room database that is written in Kotlin? 
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @User1221688, it seems you're new to SO and may not be very familiar with how it works. Your question seems to be getting a few down votes and I believe it's likely because it shows a bit of lack of research. SO users usually appreciate people posting questions after they've tried to solve their problems a bit themselves looking into blog posts and tutorials. Kotlin was originally written with the idea of being totally compatible with Java and by googling this question you'd probably have found some good explanation on how the language works already out there. Hope that to be helpful. :)

Comment: And don't worry, it took me a bit to figure it how Stack Overflow actually works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can call Kotlin function with Java and you also can call Java function with Kotlin. But you must write kotlin code in .kt file and write Java code in .java file.